# Grant access to the phone to additional users

Tags: sms, hardware, multi-user

I have a rooted Nexus 5 with multi users enabled (with gravity kk).
This is great except when I receive calls or SMS... only the account marked as "owner" receives it.
The most frustrating is that when I'm logged in with an additional user, I do receive the call (it rings) but I cannot catch it...
And SMS are just only received on the "owner" account.

I didn't find any way to change that behaviour.
Basically, I want that any user can receive the calls and receives the SMS.
How can I change that?

Comment: I believe this may be one of the reasons why multi-user is not supported on phones. I believe that [Android L](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/08/06/android-l-release-will-very-likely-include-multiple-user-support-for-phones/) will bring this support 'out of the box'.

Comment: But it's so close to being already usable... it looks like it's just a matter of turning a flag on to allow any user to catch the call (as it already rings).
I'm surprised no one already found out such hack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in Android 5.0 (built-in feature).